# Understanding android complex shape drawing

Tags: android, shapes, android-drawable

I want to have a shape consisting of a circle and a line. I probably just don't understand how things work here.

First, I thought about creating a vertical line by rotating a line shape.

```
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="90"
    >
    <shape android:shape="line">
        <stroke
            android:width="2dp"
            android:dashWidth="2dp"
            android:dashGap="4dp"
            android:color="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
            />
    </shape>
</rotate>
```

This does not create a vertical line as expected, it creates a horizontal line to me: [image: horizontal line]. Whenever I change the `fromDegrees` attribute to 90, I have a vertical one. `toDegrees` is just ignored.

```
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="90"
    android:toDegrees="190"
    >
    <shape android:shape="line">
        <stroke
            android:width="2dp"
            android:dashWidth="2dp"
            android:dashGap="4dp"
            android:color="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
            />
    </shape>
</rotate>
```

The result is now [image: vertical line].

Ok, so, I don't understand, but whatever. Let's add a circle so that I get something like this: [image: vertical line with circle]

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <rotate android:fromDegrees="90">
            <shape android:shape="line">
                <stroke
                    android:width="2dp"
                    android:dashWidth="2dp"
                    android:dashGap="4dp"
                    android:color="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <stroke android:color="#000" android:width="2dp" />
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

What I get is just a circle: [image: circle]
Having thought that the circle fills the entire size of the shape, being drawn over the entire line, I added a `scale` element to have the circle scaled 50% down.

```
<scale
    android:scaleWidth="50%"
    android:scaleHeight="50%">
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <stroke android:color="#000" android:width="2dp" />
    </shape>
</scale>
```

After that, the circle just disappeared and I got only the line again.
So, can anyone help me understand, what's going on here?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15239304/1064689
The rotate degrees refers to animation.