# Create a separator that is a vertical line that is not straight

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I can create a separator view like a pipe `|` with something like:

```
<View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:background="@color/black" />
```

But how can I create a separator that is like `/` or `\` i.e. a line that is not straight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `android:rotation` attribute.

e.g.

```
<View
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
    android:rotation="45"
    android:background="@color/black" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom drawable like below

```
<item>
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="45"
        android:toDegrees="45"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%" >
        <shape
            android:shape="line"
            android:top="1dip" >
            <stroke
                android:width="1dip"
                android:color="#FF0000" />
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>
```

Source:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15239304/2179495