# How to make EditText cursor italic?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I have an `EditText` with italic hint and text. And I want to have ***italic*** cursor for it. How do I do that? I couldn't find any post about it in Stack Overflow. Can I do that without custom cursor drawable?
In Microsoft Office when you select italic, the cursor automatically becomes italic. I want to have that italic cursor.

[image: my EditText]

Comment: in the editText attributes for cursors, there's nothing other than android:textCursorDrawable that relates to your question. You'd need to have a custom drawable for a slanted cursor

Comment: Whats the effect of `android:textStyle="italic"` on cursor ?

Comment: `android:textStyle="italic"` didn't have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create drawable like this. Choose color u want and angle you want. "itlic_cursor.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:viewportHeight="24"
    android:width="30dp"
    android:height="30dp"></vector>
```

This is what I got. If u want to add another italic cursor, first get png or jpg image and convert it to SVG.  Then convert that SVG to drawable using http://a-student.github.io/SvgToVectorDrawableConverter.Web/

then add it to edit text XML like below

```
android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/itlic_cursor"
```

Comment: If you want drawable shape you can find line with angle https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15237582/how-rotate-line-in-android-xml here answer. If u can create what line u want using photoshop or what ever. It can be converted into vector drawable like i mentioned above

Comment: @Lucefer go for this link, you will get help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11554078/set-textcursordrawable-programmatically